# OCMock verify fails

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I am trying out OCMock to test if a fetchContactsOnLoad  method was called on viewDidLoad. The VC code below.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    [self fetchContactsOnLoad];
}

-(void)fetchContactsOnLoad {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    [self.output doSomething:[ContactListRequest new]];
}
```

And the test below.

```
- (void)testFetchContactsOnLoadInvoked {
    id vcMock = OCMClassMock([ContactListViewController class]);
    [vcMock view];
    OCMVerify([vcMock fetchContactsOnLoad]);
```

}

The method gets called when I run the test since I can see the printout of NSLog but fails the test.
What am I missing on my test? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, let me try to dissuade you of trying to test whether `fetchContactsOnLoad` was called. It's better to test that the *results* of calling `fetchContactsOnLoad` take place.

That said, let's continue. How could you test that `fetchContactsOnLoad` was called? This is called a "partial mock" because you're mocking only *part* of your object, but want to keep everything else. (Again, this is usually a bad idea. But it can be handy for legacy code.)

The way I would do it would be with the legacy testing technique Subclass and Override Method. In my test code, I'd create a special subclass:

```
@interface TestableContactListViewController : ContactListViewController
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger fetchContactsOnLoadCount;
@end

@implementation TestableContactListViewController

- (void)fetchContactsOnLoad {
    self.fetchContactsOnLoadCount += 1;
}

@end
```

With this in place, the test would look like this:

```
- (void)testLoadingView_ShouldInvokeFetchContactsOnLoad {
    TestableContactListViewController *sut = [[TestableContactListViewController alloc] init];

    [sut view];

    XCTAssertEquals(sut.fetchContactsOnLoadCount, 1);
}
```

Note: This does not involve any mocking frameworks. I created a partial mock by hand. When dealing with mocks (or partial mocks), I recommend starting by hand. Once it becomes tedious, then a mocking framework will make you faster. But you'll write better tests with the knowledge you gained.

Comment: A partial mock did the job. I'm curious about the risks involved with partial mocks and would appreciate some examples. 
While waiting for someone to respond to my post I did create and use my own mock objects but it is requiring so much extra code and repetition. I'm fine with doing the extra unless I find something that does the job of creating mocks for me automatically. Another issue with creating my own mocks, most of the time Xcode coverage do not pick up that a method was used(Perhaps another issue to be posted but Google results seem to be rare). Thanks!

Comment: There are no technical risks per se, but having to use partial mocks is usually a design smell; namely that a class does too much. Normally it's better to separate the behaviour that doesn't need to be mocked from the behaviour that needs to be mocked and then put the two pieces into different classes. In such cases you can use normal mocks. OCMock added partial mocks mainly to work around the class design of some of Apple's classes in the base frameworks.